# Connecting switch to WiFi router but wireless?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, lan

I have in house ( so no enterprise solutions :D ) 16port switch to that switch is connected 10 devices via LAN.

Than in other part of the house there is Wifi router ( classic asus wifi 2.4Ghz/5Ghz with 4 LAN ports at the back ) which is working as DHCP for the NW.

What would be the best way to connect that switch to that wifi router so all the devices are at one LAN under one 10.0.0.x range ? ( it must be via WiFi, I can't run cable between them )

Currently what I have tried is to connect TP-LINK CPE210 as client to the one of the switch ports, which have as result provided access to internet for all devices connected to the switch, but on other hand I can't reliably connect to the devices from PC connected to one of the Asus wifi routers LAN ports, they show up sometimes but its unreliable. Not sure how to solve this.

Comment: If your router doesn't support WDS, you'll need a bridge. I think you can build one with two CPE210's.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: That's only assuming OP cannot run a regular cable between the devices, no?

Comment: @grawity "( it must be via WiFi, I can't run cable between them )"

Comment: Correct can't run a cable, if I could it would be simple matter of just connecting the switch to port on wifi router...

Comment: Available devices that I have: Asus RT-AC86U, Asus RT-AC66U, TP-LINK CPE210, 16port switch

Comment: I bet the two Asus units support WDS, allowing you to use them as a bridge.